# varying stat_binhex() size in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to use the `stat_binhex()` in ggplot2 to drop hex tiles on a plot, and the automatic settings vary the color of the bins, depending on count. That is, all the hexes are the same size, but have different colors.

I want to vary the size of the hex symbol itself! so that some are bigger than others... and i also want to vary color based on a third variable. I read through the documentation of ggplot2 and couldn't find any way to do this. The `*hexbin*` package has an option like this (lattice) but its `plot()` functions are maddening, so I was hoping to stay in ggplot2. Any other suggestions would be extremely helpful, as well.

If you know Kirk Goldsberry's NBA shot charts on Grantland, that's very similar to what I'd like to accomplish with my dataset.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839702/using-both-color-and-size-attributes-in-hexagon-binning-ggplot2

Comment: yes, this is a useful discussion - but that thread petered out without concluding that ggplot2 was unable to handle two dimensions (i.e. size and colour) at once!

Their other solutions are hit-or-miss. I have heard good things about ggplot2 but if that is the final word on its stat_binhex abilities, that's not very encouraging.

Comment: Well, you are free to improve ggplot2 abilities. Code is [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2).