# Mapping variables to hexagon size and color with hex_bin

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

So, I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894460/mapping-variable-to-hexagon-size-with-geom-hex) about how to map a variable to hexagon size a while ago and tried to modify it so I could use it for my purpose of drawing basketball shot charts. I know that there have been some other threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839702/using-both-color-and-size-attributes-in-hexagon-binning-ggplot2), but none I've read in the past answered my question. The first one does help but I'm stuck with one little problem:

Let's say I have a data frame with 4 variables, x, y, value (of points the shot has; in basketball it's either 2 or 3, depending on how far from the basket you take the shot), and outcome (1 for shot made, 0 for shot missed), on 250 observations. 250 shots with x and y coordinates, value and outcome.

Example:

```
     x         y     value outcome
1 169.7650 -316.5726     3   0
2  75.0775 -182.3126     2   0
3  94.0150 -147.4050     2   1
4 109.1650 -138.0068     2   0
5  87.7025 -146.0624     2   1

# dput below:

structure(list(x = c(169.765, 75.0775, 94.015, 109.165, 87.7025), 
y = c(-316.5726, -182.3126, -147.405, -138.0068, -146.0624), 
value = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), outcome = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), 
.Names = c("x", "y", "value", "outcome"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Negative coordinates because (0/0) is in the top left corner. With the code from the first thread I linked above I was able to bin my data, I just can't figure out how to operate on the binned data. This is what I got so far:

[image: Imgur-Link]

From this code:

```
# devtools::install_git("https://github.com/hadley/densityvis.git")

library(densityvis)

bin = hex_bin(df$x, df$y, var4=df$value, frequency.to.area=TRUE)
hexes = hex_coord_df(x=bin$x, y=bin$y, 
                     width=attr(bin,"width"), height=attr(bin,"height"),
                     size=bin$size)
hexes$rightness = rep(bin$col, each=6)

ggplot(hexes, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=rightness, group=id))
```

With the size displaying how many shots were TAKEN from the given area. Color gives the value of the shots from that area. What I want is something like points per shot, meaning: summing up the points per bin and then dividing by the number of shots taken, ranging from 0 (no shots made) to 3 (all shots made from a 3 point area) and displaying only bins with at least two shots TAKEN.

I know it is a lot to ask, and it's my problem that I can't do it on my own. But if anyone had the time, any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**: 
I uploaded the csv sample that created the above image [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uws69wt6sx344v/sample_data.csv?dl=0).
I don't know if it's cool to post 300 lines of code into a question, that's why I link [geotheory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156245/geotheory)'s code [here](https://gist.github.com/geotheory/5748388). My slightly modified example is in the code bracket above, I just ran

```
df <- read.csv("sample_data.csv", header=TRUE)
```

beforehand.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if you could make a small pie chart for every coordinate? Size would correspond to the number of shots taken and pieces of pie would correspond  to proportion of 2/3 points per location.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, thank you! Though I think it might be too much, because you'd have to study each bin seperetaly to get an idea of how player X shoots from that spot Y, whereas hexagons colored by efficiency (points per shot) give you a better total overview on from where that player feels most comfortable taking his shots, no?

Comment: @roman_luštrik check out the `ggsubplot` package

Comment: @geotheory uff, that package is a lot of work. :)

Comment: It might look it but I've actually found it pretty straightforward to e.g. overlay graphs on maps. Just look for a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the hex_bin code stands the zero value observations are filtered out.  This can be changed by removing the `& var4 > 0` argument from `clean_xy` (line 117 in github).  Then the following:

```
df$pts = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) if(df$outcome[i] == 1) df$pts[i] = df$value[i]
bin = hex_bin(df$x, df$y, var4=df$pts, frequency.to.area=TRUE)
hexes = hex_coord_df(x=bin$x, y=bin$y, width=attr(bin,"width"), height=attr(bin,"height"), size=bin$size)
hexes$points = rep(bin$col, each=6)
ggplot(hexes, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=points, group=id))
```

gives you:

[image]

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It is, thank you so much! :) Could you tell me where I'd have to look when I wanted to filter out all bins with only one/two/three observations in them?

Comment: The data is binned into the `binned` object in `hex_bin`.  You'd just need to add `binned <- binned[binned$freq > 3,]` after to filter out those rows.  You may need to re-specify the plot coordinates if this filters out data that defines the extent of the ball court.

Comment: All it does for me right now is [this](http://i.imgur.com/gmENRfH.png) with `binned <- binned[binned$freq > 2,]` where I was hoping the bins would stay where they were before and keep their size, just minus the smaller ones. But I'll figure it out. Thanks again, I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: I think that is what you've asked it to do.  Try using `coord_cartesian` with `xlim` and `ylim` arguments to specify the original plot limits.